# Postgresql: "error syntax error at end of input"

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL database and get an error saying `pq: syntax error at end of input`

```golang
package utils

// DBConnect connection to PG database
func DBConnect() *sql.DB {
    // env := LoadEnvVariables()

    connStr := "postgres://user:password@127.0.0.1/lybl?sslmode=disable"
    fmt.Println(connStr)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    return db
}
```

Don't know what I'm missing here

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119786/syntax-error-at-end-of-input-in-postgresql

Comment: It helped a lot ! A query was executed with the returned `*sql.DB` value and the error came from the query ; I was using `?` prepared statement instead of `$1, ...`